# Setting up a symbol server over https (S)

Tags: debugging, windbg, symbols

Is there a way to convert a HTTP symbol server to HTTPS? I mean, how do I implement my existing symbols server (HTTP) to run on HTTPS instead.
Can debugger support HTTPS?
Also,
Is there some way I could implement authentication to open the link?

The IT demands as such, although I do not see any reason for it, since we are already over a VPN and the server will remain on intranet.

Comment: Many attacks result from *inside* the company (frustrated employees etc.). Although I'm not sure whether a symbol server can be exploited, it adds another level of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol server can be accessed via https there is no problem doing this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537994%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also if authentication is required it can be controlled via a pop-up dialog: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545465(v=vs.85).aspx

If necessary (it shouldn't be as the default is to allow user interaction for authentication) set the option: using `!sym prompts` or `.symopt -0x80000`.

If you want to provide symbol store access over the internet then there is a MSDN page on configuring IIS to allow access: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549781(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I did go through the first one, but somehow missed the HTTPS support. The third link is nice. It doesn't show up in my google search :/